# Conditional formatting based on another list of elements

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to do conditional formatting over a list of elements if they appear in another list.

Let's say:

```
ColumnA: List of element to do conditional formatting
ColumnB: Expected result (hardcoded the background)
ColumnF: List of important items
```

Problem I am trying to solve:

- ColumnA will be changing constantly, it can be used for meal monitoring for example, but ColumnF will change less frequently, and it will be in another Tab or even another document that will be linked.
- The purpose is to be able to change the background of the elements in ColumnA if they exists in the ColumnF to give quickly visually identification this is an important element to have.

Let's say it is important to understand, when setting up a meal for a week, that at least they should exists 5 ingredients with a specific background.

Test document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pn3BWxBu_2RH5IzEbQWl3QOvjqxfzYRsCaItRWXSbBU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this custom formula

```
=match($A2, $F$2:$F5,0)
```

For an example see the second tab in your spreadsheet.

Note: to reference a list on a different tab, try

```
=match($A2, indirect("Sheet1!$F$2:$F5"),0)
```

Check the example on the third tab in your spreadsheet.